# Как создать правильный json из многомерного массива php?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Пытаюсь получить корзину woocommerce ajax , но при возврате json не могу собрать нормальный json:

PHP:

```
 function update_cart_ajax() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

  // $cart_content = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents();

  $ajax_cart = array();

  foreach($items as $item => $values) {

    $cart_data = array(

      'title' => wc_get_product($values['data']->get_id())->get_title(),
      'image' =>  wc_get_product($values['product_id'])->get_image(),
      'price' => get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true),
    );

    $ajax_cart[] .= $cart_data;

  } 

  $res_data = json_encode($ajax_cart);

  echo $res_data;
}
```

JS

```
function updateCart() {

  jQuery(function($){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: wp_ajax,
      data: {action: wp_actions.update_mini_cart},
      success: function(res) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(res.substr(res.length-1, 1) === '0'? res.substr(0, res.length-1) : res);
        //$('.ajax-test-cart').html(obj.image);
        console.log(obj);
      }
    });
  });

}
```

Получаю три массива , а нужен обьект с данными корзины.

```
(3) ["Array", "Array", "Array"]
0
:
"Array"
1
:
"Array"
2
:
"Array"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Comment: так вы же сами $cart_data = array(..) объявили переменную массивом...

Comment: $ajax_cart[] .= $cart_data; - точку я бы убрал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, стоит использовать параметр `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` в функции [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php):

```
$res_data = json_encode($ajax_cart, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

> **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT**
>
> Выдавать объект вместо массива при
>   использовании неассоциативного массива. Это полезно, когда принимающая
>   программа или код ожидают объект, а массив пуст. Доступно с PHP 5.3.0.

И стоит убрать конкатенацию (используется для строк, а не для массивов):

```
$ajax_cart[] .= $cart_data;
```

на:

```
$ajax_cart[] = $cart_data;
```